# Change textsize of textview with button

Tags: android

I want to implement a feature that allows user to change the textSize of a textView in another view inside the app,

So I have a button with its ＂onClick" property set to:

```
Class mainActivity
    public void increaseFont(View view)
    {
        MainViewPager.changeTextViewTextSize(mTextSize);
    }

Class MainViewPager

    static public void changeTextViewTextSize(int aTextSize)
    {
        View detailView = (View) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.details, null);
        TextView description = (TextView) detailView.findViewById(R.id.story_description);
        description.setTextSize(aTextSize);
    }
```

QUESTIONS is the textSize can't be changed when clicking the button. So how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text size can changed at run time of course. You issue is related to the method `changeTextViewTextSize`. Using the inflater you are creating a new instance of `R.layout.details`, and through it, you are looking for the TextView you want to change the text size. But that layout is not at screen. It is   not what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks. It does address the issues in my code.  New problem is, what if I have a listview, then I want to change the textSize in each view item by clicking button?

Comment: do you have a custom adapter?

Comment: yes. I hae a custom adapter. I save all items in the adapter and save them into array. And then find the target views from the array to change its textSize. That's how I solve it. Thanks.